# Angular + Firebase List order

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on Todo List with Angular and Firebase. I am trying to use @angular/cdk for dragdrop this todo-list. I want to save the order of todo-items when I change them with dragdrop. Is there a way to save and store order of items in firebase? (I am using firestore documents and collections)

Comment: You need to add one field in firestore. Field is index. Then on change order you need to update all list data index one by one

Comment: Are you asking about demo code or just explaination?

Comment: @AmanGojariya Is index field something like default in firestore? Like if I manually set index to 2 it comes second??

Comment: Yes, you need to add manual field of index

Comment: @AmanGojariya Ah yea, I get you. But there could be like 20 items. What then? Like I must update them all?

Comment: Yes you need to update all item index one by one

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to add index field in your firestore collection. Then after, in the frontend on index change you need to update all collection items indexes one by one.

Comment: You mean I should call update service on like 50 items? There could be even more items

Comment: Yes, because of you have change index of 50th item to 2nd then 3rd item to 49th item index is incremented by one so you need to change index all of the list item.